# SQL to replace field content with content from another table if found

Tags: mysql, sql, database, left-join, translation

Consider the following tables for a multilingual event database

```
events
  id, title, content, ...

localizations
  id, table_name, row_id, field, language, text
```

What my CMS does is in case of translation store that translations in the localizations table. 
When retrieving events, the fields get overwritten by their localized texts for the appropriate language.

Thus e.g.:

```
events
  1, 'Great event', 'lorum ipsum', ...
  2, 'Another event', 'lorum ipsum', ...

localizations
  1, 'events', 1, 'title', 'es', 'Gran evento'
```

Question: is it possible to construct a mysql query that retrieves all events, with their localized titles for english, or default if not found?

I suspect it has to be a left join like this

```
SELECT e.id, e.title, e.content 
FROM `events` e 
LEFT JOIN localizations loc ON loc.row_id = e.id
```

But it has to join only if loc.field = 'title' and loc.language='en'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is `LEFT JOIN` as you have already discovered, combined with `COALESCE()`. That function returns the first non-null value from among its arguments.

```
 SELECT e.id, e.title,
        COALESCE(ca.text, es.text, e.content) content
   FROM events e
   LEFT JOIN localizations ca ON ca.row_id = e.id AND ca.language = 'ca'
   LEFT JOIN localizations es ON es.row_id = e.id AND es.language = 'es'
```

From this, in the result set's `content` column, you will get the Catalan text if it is there. If not, and the Spanish text is there, you'll get that. Otherwise you'll get whatever is in the main table.